# Ansible + Ubuntu 18.04 + MySQL = "The PyMySQL (Python 2.7 and Python 3.X) or MySQL-python (Python 2.X) module is required."

Tags: python, mysql, ansible

I’m seeing the above message on multiple playbooks using Ansible 2.8 on Ubuntu 18.04. In the interests of simplicity I’ve reproduced it using this basic playbook for a single node Drupal server. https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-for-devops/tree/master/drupal; this playbook works fine on earlier versions of ubuntu, but not on 18.04 which I understand includes python3 by default.

I’ve used vagrant to create the base machine, which shows the following:

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ which python2
/usr/bin/python2
$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
$ python --version
Python 2.7.15rc1
$ python2 --version
Python 2.7.15rc1
$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.7
```

Which seems to be telling me that both python 2 and python 3 are installed, but that 2.7 is the default as that is what responds to $ python --version.

I have tried all the suggestions described in this article: https://www.rollnorocks.com/2018/12/ansible-python-and-mysql-untangling-the-mess/
Including specifying the

```
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3
```

But nothing affects the message. The edited -vvv output from the playbook run is below. Has anyone got any more ideas about either the problem or solution.

```
TASK [Remove the MySQL test database.] ****************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /vagrant/provisioning/playbook.yml:96
<10.1.1.11> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: mt-ansible-user
<10.1.1.11> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 
.
.
.
Using module file /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/database/mysql/mysql_db.py
<10.1.1.11> PUT /home/mt-tools-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-21287bh5dK5/tmp7pOKOH TO /home/mt-ansible-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1558868136.49-16683638151793
1/AnsiballZ_mysql_db.py                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
<10.1.1.11> SSH: EXEC sftp -b - -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/home/mt-tools-user/.ssh/mt_ansible_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthent
ication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="mt-ansible-user"' -o ConnectTimeout=                                                                          
10 -o ControlPath=/home/mt-tools-user/.ansible/cp/af4de51057 '[10.1.1.11]'                                                                                                                                                                    
<10.1.1.11> (0, 'sftp> put /home/mt-tools-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-21287bh5dK5/tmp7pOKOH /home/mt-ansible-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1558868136.49-166836
381517931/AnsiballZ_mysql_db.py\n', '')                                                                                                                                                                                                       
<10.1.1.11> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: mt-ansible-user
<10.1.1.11> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/home/mt-tools-user/.ssh/mt_ansible_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthenticatio
n=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="mt-ansible-user"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o                                                                           
ControlPath=/home/mt-tools-user/.ansible/cp/af4de51057 10.1.1.11 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'chmod u+x /home/mt-ansible-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1558868136.49-1668363815                                                                          
17931/ /home/mt-ansible-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1558868136.49-166836381517931/AnsiballZ_mysql_db.py && sleep 0'"'"''                                                                                                                    
<10.1.1.11> (0, '', '')
<10.1.1.11> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: mt-ansible-user
<10.1.1.11> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/home/mt-tools-user/.ssh/mt_ansible_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthenticatio
n=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="mt-ansible-user"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o                                                                           
ControlPath=/home/mt-tools-user/.ansible/cp/af4de51057 -tt 10.1.1.11 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo -H -S -n  -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-qwjewg                                                                          
qckuyapsxnkbqoegainrkyiinc ; /usr/bin/python3 /home/mt-ansible-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1558868136.49-166836381517931/AnsiballZ_mysql_db.py'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' &
& sleep 0'"'"''
<10.1.1.11> (1, 'BECOME-SUCCESS-qwjewgqckuyapsxnkbqoegainrkyiinc\r\n\r\n{"msg": "The PyMySQL (Python 2.7 and Python 3.X) or MySQL-python (Python 2.X) module is req
uired.", "failed": true, "invocation": {"module_args": {"db": "test", "state": "absent", "name": "test", "login_host": "localhost", "login_port": 3306, "encoding":
"", "collation": "", "connect_timeout": 30, "config_file": "/root/.my.cnf", "single_transaction": false, "quick": true, "ignore_tables": [], "login_user": null, "
login_password": null, "login_unix_socket": null, "target": null, "client_cert": null, "client_key": null, "ca_cert": null}}}\r\n', 'Shared connection to 10.1.1.11
closed.\r\n')
<10.1.1.11> Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Shared connection to 10.1.1.11 closed.
<10.1.1.11> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: mt-ansible-user
<10.1.1.11> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/home/mt-tools-user/.ssh/mt_ansible_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthenticatio
n=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="mt-ansible-user"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o
ControlPath=/home/mt-tools-user/.ansible/cp/af4de51057 10.1.1.11 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'rm -f -r /home/mt-ansible-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1558868136.49-16683638151
7931/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.1.1.11> (0, '', '')
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your remote host is telling you:

> The PyMySQL (Python 2.7 and Python 3.X) or MySQL-python (Python 2.X) module is required.

Did you follow the recommendations and install the required `pymysql` python package on your remote host ?

For a quick test, on your remote host:

- if using python 2.7: `sudo pip install pymysql`
- if using python 3.x: `sudo pip3 install pymysql`

Once tested, to make sure this dependency is always present, add a task in your playbook prior to launching any mysql task:

```
- name: Make sure pymysql is present
  become: true # needed if the other tasks are not played as root
  pip:
    name: pymysql
    state: present
```

You should not have to specify the `executable` option in this case (see [doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/pip_module.html)) as it will default to your `ansible_python_interpreter`

Comment: can confirm this is working with Debian 10.1 (replacing need for `MySQL-python` package)

Comment: Working with Ansible 2.9.6 and Ubuntu server 20.04. Note that `become: true` has been replaced with `become: yes`.

Comment: @rpm192 `true` and `yes` are two equivalent boolean values in an ansible yaml file. Same goes for `false` and `no`

Comment: Further note on the executable, I had a task in a playbook delegated to different host. I needed to set `ansible_python_interpreter` to `auto` to get *pip* to pickup the right version; to do that needs a ``set_fact`` with both ``delegate_to: [server]`` AND ``delegate_facts: true`` - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57661002/763419

Answer (score 8):

No need to install `pip` and python tools to target host to solve this.

Another way is just to install `python3-mysqldb` package on target host:

```
- name: "Install ansible python3 mysql dependency"
  apt:
    name: python3-mysqldb
    state: latest
```

Worked well for bunch of Debian 10/11/12 servers in case of mine.

Comment: that wasn't enough...

Comment: It was enough in a few cases of mine. What errror do you have after installing python3-mysqldb package?

Comment: In my case (Debian 11 / maria-db), this was enough.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Rocky 8.5 - use dnf as part of your ansible playbook to install PyMySQL. Comes from the `@System` repository, so straightforward

```
  - name: Install PyMySQL
    package:
      name: python3-PyMySQL
      state: present
```