# how to set different python interpreters for local and remote hosts

Tags: ansible

Use-Case:

## Playbook 1

- when we first connect to a remote host/s, the remote host will already have some python version installed - the auto-discovery feature will find it
- now we install [ansible-docker](https://github.com/nickjj/ansible-docker) on the remote host
- from this time on: the [ansible-docker docs](https://github.com/nickjj/ansible-docker#working-with-ansibles-docker_-modules) suggest to use `ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/env python-docker`

## Playbook 2

We connect to the same host/s again, but now we must use the `/usr/bin/env python-docker` python interpreter

**What is the best way to do this?**

Currently we set `ansible_python_interpreter` on the playbook level of `Playbook 2`:

```
---
- name: DaqMon app
  vars:
  - ansible_python_interpreter: "{{ '/usr/bin/env python-docker' }}"
```

This works, but this will also change the python interpreter of the local actions. And thus the [local actions](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation) will fail, because (`python-docker` does not exist locally).

- the current workaround is to explicitly specify the  `ansible_python_interpreter` on every local-action which is tedious and error-prone

**Questions**:

- the ideal solution is, if we could add `'/usr/bin/env python-docker'` as  fallback to [interpreter-python-fallback](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#interpreter-python-fallback) - but I think this is not possible
- is there a way to set the python interpreter only for the remote hosts - and keep the default for the localhost?
- or is it possible to explicitly override the python interpreter for the local host?

Comment: I'm not sure about ansible way, but you can create and use virtualenv which you can use just by activating it. every thing will get installed on virtualenv and you will not face any issue with your local environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to the other useful answers I found an easy solution:

- on the playbook level we set the python interpreter to `/usr/bin/env python-docker`
- then we use a `set_fact` task to override the interpreter for localhost only

  - we must also [delegate the facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegated-facts)
  - we can use the magic `ansible_playbook_python` variable, which refers to the python interpreter that was used on the (local) Ansible host to start the playbook: see [Ansible docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts)

Here are the important parts at the start of `Playbook 2`:

```yaml
---
- name: Playbook 2
  vars:
  - ansible_python_interpreter: "{{ '/usr/bin/env python-docker' }}"
  ...
  tasks:
  - set_fact:
      ansible_python_interpreter: '{{ ansible_playbook_python }}'
    delegate_to: localhost    
    delegate_facts: true
```

Answer (score 6):

You should set the `ansible_python_interpreter` on the host level.

So yes, it's possible to explicitly set the interpreter for [localhost in your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory/implicit_localhost.html).

```
localhost   ansible_connection=local ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python
```

And I assume that you could also use `set_fact` on `hostvars[<host>].ansible_python_interpreter` on your localhost or docker host.

There is a [brillant article about `set_fact` on `hostvars`](https://medium.com/@george.shuklin/pocking-into-others-hostvars-69475ff0a8cf) ! ;-P

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. I've upvoted your answer and added my solution.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `set_fact` for `ansible_python_interpreter` at host level  in the first playbook.

Comment: I wanted to edit the answer to correct the type «_i**n** the first playbook_», but I'm not allowed as the change need to be at least 6 chars…

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. I've upvoted your answer and added my solution.

Answer (score -1):

Globally, use the `interpreter_python` key in the `[defaults]` section of the `ansible.cfg` file.

```
interpreter_python = auto_silent
```